# Model not being posted by view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a "Fault" view model. This is returned to a "FaultDetails" view from a "Fault" controller as follows:

```
return View("FaultDetails", faultVM);
```

The "FaultDetails" view then displays correctly, presenting data from the view model.

The model is declared in the view as follows:

```
@model TVS.ESB.BamPortal.Website.Models.FaultViewModel
```

I would like the user to then be able to post the view model to a "Resubmit" action on the "Fault" controller so I've added the following to the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Resubmit", "Fault"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Resubmit Message" />
}
```

And I've created the following action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Resubmit(FaultViewModel vm)
{
    ...
```

My problem is, the view is not posting the view model to this new action. I've set a breakpoint on the action, the vm variable is set to null. I also checked the POST in Fiddler, no data was passed in the Body.

Can anyone see why my view is not posting its model?

---

Thanks for the answers, I found the @Html.HiddenFor is just what I needed:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Resubmit", "Fault"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MessageData);
    <input type="submit" value="Resubmit Message" />
}
```

Comment: Your view does not have any form controls so there is nothing posted to the `Resubmit()` method

Comment: Your form is empty...there is no inputs in your form..that is why on posting `FaultViewModel` vm is null because there is nothing to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Resubmit", "Fault"))`
 {

```
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FaultDescription)
```

`<input type="submit" value="Resubmit Message" />`
}

You need have some form data to post!.

Comment: Thank you - I've been away from MVC for a while!. What I had done looks a bit stupid now but, the view did already have the model populated that I wanted to post to the controller. What I have discovered is the HiddenFor Html helper which is just what I needed. I have now added to my question